# Why typescript compain about types even though I have a condition to evaluate the data?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Poorly worded question, I didn't know how to ask this.

I have a condition that evaluate data received from a remote server. If it's not false, it contains an object.

```
interface serverData {
  data: boolean|{a: number, b: string, c: number, d: string},
  extra: boolean,
}

getRemoteData(): serverData {
    return {
      "extra": false,
      "data": {
        a: 15460514569,
        b: "mia6bahBai",
        c: 2019,
        d: 'Lorem Ipsum'
      }
    }
}

dothings() {
  var response = this.getRemoteData()

  if(response.data !== false) { // check if type is serverData or false

    let obj = new Data(response.data) // Expect serverData
  }
}
```

For development purposes, `response.data` return a static object but may return `false` eventually.

Typescript complains:

> Argument of type 'true | { a: number; b: string; c: number; d:
>   string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'serverData'.   Type
>   'true' is not assignable to type 'serverData'..

Typescript is getting in my nerves. I have a condition in place to mitigate errors and do the right thing depending of the data received. What does typescript expect from me here?

Comment: I think the type of `data` is `boolean | { a: number; b: string; c: number; d: string; }` which is `false | true | { a: number; b: string; c: number; d: string; }` so your check is only excluding false from the union. try `typeof response.data !== 'boolean'`

Comment: Apparently that value is initially a Boolean or that object. You've only ruled out false, so it could still be true. Without more context it's hard to say how you should be solving this. Why false rather than e.g. null?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir from the description so far it seems more likely that the original type shouldn't include true, but we'll see.

Comment: I'm sorry I could have put more stuff in the question. I've updated it. Thanks folks

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir  Oh so I could do `false|{}` instead of `boolean|{...}`... I think it's working. :O

Comment: So *could* response.data be true? In that case, should Data's constructor accept that, or do you need another conditional branch, or what? If not, why include that possible value in the original type? We have no context to determine that, TypeScript is currently telling you correctly that your types aren't consistent.

Comment: @HypeWolf if you r server return `false | {}` then yes that would be the best solution. If it can return `true` as well then the first check I suggested will do the job

Comment: Wouldn't `null` or `undefined` be better suited for an object that does not exist?

Comment: @JakeHolzinger I read somewhere that I should avoid `null` although I love using it. But in this case `null` or `undefined` could mean the server didn't respond or didn't respond properly. `false` would ensure the value was intended.

Comment: I would agree that `null` should be avoided in most cases as it is a common cause of null reference exceptions, but there are valid use cases for `null`. I would posit, however, that the use of `null` is preferred over attempting to conflate the existence of an object with the object itself.

Comment: How looks the `constructor` of class `Data` like? From the question and the comment on the `new Data(response.data)` line I think you are passing the wrong object type to it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`let obj = new Data(response.data)`

The problem is that typescript doesn't know if `response.data` value is a `true`, `false`, or your "real data";

I would suggest:

```
interface RealData {
  a: number,
  b: string,
  c: number,
  d: string
}

type ServerData = RealData | false;

interface ServerResponse {
  data: ServerData;
  extra: boolean;
}
```

```
let obj = new Data(response.data as RealData)
```

Comment: Your approach is cleaver. Thank you my friend. I just learned a lot with your answer.

Comment: If `response` is declared as an object of type `ServerResponse`, the compiler **knows** that `response.data` is an object of type `RealData` and your assertion is useless. If it is not declared correctly, the compiler complains about `response` not having the property `data`.

Answer (score -1):

I think that

```
interface serverData {
  data: boolean|{a: number, b: string, c: number, d: string},
  extra: boolean,
}
```

Should be

```
interface serverData {
  data: {a: number, b: string, c: number, d: string},
  extra: boolean,
}
```

Because it you don't declare whether it's false or true which is only done in extra.

Comment: `data` could be false if ther server didn't have any data to send. As I said in the comment below a few seconds ago, `null` or `undefined` could mean the server didn't respond or didn't respond properly. `false` would ensure the value was intended.

Comment: @HypeWolf why not just send an empty object to indicate no data was sent? Or, more importantly, why not use an appropriate HTTP status code?

Comment: @Seiyria I could send a 204 No Content you are right.